# Graphics Not Working After 17.04 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, graphics, 17.04

I have run into an issue with the upgrade to 17.04. Whenever I turn on my computer, it flashes the kernel info multiple times and does not allow me to use a GUI. I can still go into a TTY, however. I am using a RX460 video card with an i5-4690K. I have looked at the Xorg logs, and there is nothing in there that should cause this, though I will post them if wanted. Thank you for your help.
If it helps, I was using the amdgpu-pro driver before the upgrade. I have since removed it.

EDIT: After a quick thought, even trying to use GNOME with wayland instead of Xorg doesn't work.

EDIT: Even after reinstall, this is still an issue

Comment: I would open sessions o VT1 and VT2.  In terminal, run "startx". That will generate error logs in /var/log that will hrlp see what is wrong. I dont know what RX460 is, but if it needs firmware or drive, you will see. Do this because it by passes the login manager, which may fail for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong: there were some xcb libraries in my /usr/local/lib folder. I don't know why they were there, considering that they belonged to no package, but I found them by making lightdm save its logs, because they kept getting overwritten. I just copied all of the libraries as a backup, then deleted the originals.